# What does ingestion time mean in CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

In the structure of an event of Cloudwatch :

```
'events': [
        {
            'logStreamName': 'string',
            'timestamp': 123,
            'message': 'string',
            'ingestionTime': 123,
            'eventId': 'string'
        },
    ]
```

What does **ingestionTime** mean  ?

In this [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_OutputLogEvent.html) they are saying :

> ingestionTime
>
> ```
> The time the event was ingested.
> ```

Which I find still unclear.

Comment: <sarcasm>I can't imagine why...</sarcasm>

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are two timestamp fields, here.

The `timestamp` is the time the event **was said to have occurred**, according to the message that was sent to CloudWatch.

The `ingestionTime` is the time CloudWatch actually received the message about the event.

The difference between the two -- assuming all clocks are accurate -- is the delay between when the event occurred and when CloudWatch received and "ingested" (was fed, ate, consumed) the message about the event.

Comment: Is this timestamp field is calculated from the time which is logged in the message which is sent to the cloud watch?

Comment: trust aws to add a totally useless feature to their generally unusable logging system

Comment: leaving aside the confusion... ¿which one do you use for searching logs? ¿timestamp or ingestiontime?

Answer (score 4):

According to my own investigations it looks like `lastEventTimestamp` is time of last event received by CloudWatch, however its update is slightly delayed, according to the documentation:

> The `lastEventTime` value updates on an eventual consistency basis. It typically updates in less than an hour from ingestion, but may take longer in some rare situations.

On the other hand, `lastIngestionTime` shows the **indicated** timestamp of last event received to the stream. And this one gets updated immediately after the event was received by CloudWatch service.

So if you are looking for timestamp of most recent event in the stream, you are probably looking for `lastIngestionTime`.